# How to convert a R function into a C++ function using Rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, function, rcpp

I have defined the following function:

```
pij = function(vec){
  out = vec %*% t(vec)
  diag(out) = NA
  out = sum(out, na.rm = T)
  return(out)
}
```

where `vec` is a vector, for instance `vec = rnorm(10^4,0,1)`.

I would like to know how this function can be written in C++ using the Rcpp package.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I would suggest looking into RcppArmadillo for this kind of matrix manipulation. The total amount of code required isn't that high. c.f. Armadillo's `accu()` for `sum()` and `.diag().zeros()` to remove the diagonal component.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have not tried anything so far because I do not know how C++ works. I will take a look at Rcpp Armadillo.

Comment: Why do you want to move this to C++? If it is for performance reasons, than you should not create a big (symmetric) matrix just to sum its elements. That's a lot of unnecessary memory allocation.

Comment: What is your suggestion then?

Comment: I am old-school. I would suggest you try to learn a little how C++ works first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest thinking about the math behind the problem first. For a vector `v` you are trying to calculate

```
sum_{i=1}^{N-1} sum_{j=i+1}^{N} 2 * v_i * v_j
```

You can do that by creating the matrix `v_i * v_j` first, but that can be expensive if `v` is large. So it is easier to implement the double sum directly in C++:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double pij_cpp(Rcpp::NumericVector vec) {
  double out{0.0};
  int N = vec.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < N; ++j) {
      out += 2 * vec[i] * vec[j];
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

However, the formula above can actually be rearranged:

```
2 * sum_{i=1}^{N-1} v_i * sum_{j=i+1}^{N} v_j
```

which allows us to get rid of the double loop by starting at the high end and going to the low end:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double pij_opt(Rcpp::NumericVector vec) {
  double out{0.0};
  double sum{0.0};
  int N = vec.size();
  for (int i = N -1; i > 0; --i) {
    sum += vec[i];
    out += sum * vec[i-1];
  }
  return 2 * out;
}
```

We can compare these versions with your R code and an Armadillo based version for a vector of length `10^4`:

```
> bench::mark(pij(vec), pij_cpp(vec), pij_opt(vec), pij_arma(vec))
# A tibble: 4 x 14
  expression     min    mean  median     max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time result
  <chr>      <bch:t> <bch:t> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm> <list>
1 pij(vec)   716.4ms 716.4ms 716.4ms 716.4ms      1.40    1.49GB     1     1      716ms <dbl …
2 pij_cpp(v…  59.9ms  61.4ms  61.5ms  62.3ms     16.3     2.49KB     0     9      552ms <dbl …
3 pij_opt(v…  14.2µs  15.6µs  14.9µs 864.5µs  64072.      2.49KB     0 10000      156ms <dbl …
4 pij_arma(… 834.5ms 834.5ms 834.5ms 834.5ms      1.20    2.49KB     0     1      834ms <dbl …
# ... with 3 more variables: memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

R and Armadillo are about on par (and probably limited by the memory allocation). The first C++ version is faster by a factor of 10, the second by a factor of 50000!

Full code:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double pij_arma(arma::vec vec) {
  arma::mat out = vec * vec.t();
  out.diag().zeros();
  return arma::accu(out);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double pij_cpp(Rcpp::NumericVector vec) {
  double out{0.0};
  int N = vec.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < N; ++j) {
      out += 2 * vec[i] * vec[j];
    }
  }
  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double pij_opt(Rcpp::NumericVector vec) {
  double out{0.0};
  double sum{0.0};
  int N = vec.size();
  for (int i = N -1; i > 0; --i) {
    sum += vec[i];
    out += sum * vec[i-1];
  }
  return 2 * out;
}


/*** R
pij = function(vec){
  out = vec %*% t(vec)
  diag(out) = NA
  out = sum(out, na.rm = T)
  return(out)
}


set.seed(42)
vec = rnorm(10^4,0,1)
pij(vec)

bench::mark(pij(vec), pij_cpp(vec), pij_opt(vec), pij_arma(vec))
*/
```

For completeness: This is really a question of algorithm, so even a `for` loop in R is faster than `pij_cpp`:

```
pij_opt_r <- function(vec) {
  out <- 0
  sum <- 0
  N <- length(vec)
  for (i in seq.int(from = N, to = 2, by = -1)) {
    sum <- sum + vec[i]
    out <- out + sum * vec[i-1]
  }
  2 * out
}
```

Using vectorized functions in R is even faster, but still not as fast as `pij_opt`:

```
pij_opt_r2 <- function(vec) {
  N <- length(vec)
  vec <- rev(vec)
  sums <- cumsum(vec)
  2 * sum(vec[2:N] * sums[1:N-1])
}
```

Full benchmark:

```
> bench::mark(pij(vec), pij_cpp(vec), pij_opt(vec), pij_opt_r(vec), pij_opt_r2(vec), pij_arma(vec))
# A tibble: 6 x 14
  expression     min     mean   median     max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time result
  <chr>      <bch:t> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm> <list>
1 pij(vec)   733.6ms  733.6ms  733.6ms 733.6ms      1.36    1.49GB     1     1      734ms <dbl …
2 pij_cpp(v…    60ms  61.41ms  60.84ms  64.2ms     16.3     2.49KB     0     9      553ms <dbl …
3 pij_opt(v…  14.2µs  15.83µs  15.35µs 750.1µs  63164.      2.49KB     0 10000      158ms <dbl …
4 pij_opt_r… 981.1µs   1.04ms   1.02ms   1.5ms    960.     119.2KB     0   480      500ms <dbl …
5 pij_opt_r…   157µs 272.95µs 241.57µs  66.3ms   3664.    547.28KB     1  1832      500ms <dbl …
6 pij_arma(… 878.4ms 878.38ms 878.38ms 878.4ms      1.14    2.49KB     0     1      878ms <dbl …
# ... with 3 more variables: memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

Comment: "I would suggest thinking about the math behind the problem first."  Nice.  There is no problem for which a first algorithm can't be improved irrespective of the language used.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a better, more direct version where C++ ends up winning a little:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double pij_cpp(const arma::vec & v) {
  arma::mat m = v * v.t();
  m.diag().zeros();
  double s = arma::as_scalar(arma::accu(m));
  return(s);
}

/*** R
library(rbenchmark)
set.seed(123)

pij <- function(vec){
  out <- vec %*% t(vec)
  diag(out) <- NA
  out <- sum(out, na.rm = T)
}

x <- rnorm(1000)

## make sure they are the same
all.equal(pij(x), pij_cpp(x))

## benchmark
benchmark(R=pij(x), Cpp=pij_cpp(x))
*/
```

On my machine, C++ is ahead:

```
R> sourceCpp("~/git/so-r/53105055/answer.cpp")

R> library(rbenchmark)

R> set.seed(123)

R> pij <- function(vec){
+   out <- vec %*% t(vec)
+   diag(out) <- NA
+   out <- sum(out, na.rm = T)
+ }

R> x <- rnorm(1000)

R> ## make sure they are the same
R> all.equal(pij(x), pij_cpp(x))
[1] TRUE

R> ## benchmark
R> benchmark(R=pij(x), Cpp=pij_cpp(x))
  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2  Cpp          100   0.127    1.000     0.283    0.356          0         0
1    R          100   0.583    4.591     2.607    4.011          0         0
R>
```

The bigger takeaway is ... that you looked at the wrong problem.  Your R function is
already highly vectorized and calls out to mostly compiled code so there was not that much to gain.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I have found:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)

rcpp_inc = "using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;"

src = "
vec vec1 = as<vec>(vecin);
mat out = vec1*trans(vec1);
out.diag().zeros();

return(wrap(accu(out)));
"
pij_rcpp = cxxfunction(signature(vecin="numeric"), src, plugin='RcppArmadillo', rcpp_inc)
```

However, it is slower than the function written in R. For instance, if I run this example,

```
set.seed(1)
x = runif(1e4)
system.time({pij_r(x)}) 
system.time({pij_rcpp(x)})
```

I get that the elapsed period is 1.101 for `pij_r` and 1.323 for `pij_rcpp`.